# Teradata-replacing self join

Tags: sql, teradata

I have table in Teradata and have trillion of record.
 Temp- with cat_nbr as PI

```
Cat_nbr | brand_Nbr |card_nbr
1       |  10       | 100
1       |   10      |101
1       |20         | 100
1       | 20        | 102
2       |10         | 100
2       | 10        |103
2       |30         |100
2       |30         |105
3       |40         |106
3       | 30        |107
```

I need to find out categories total no of customer for a particular brand.
Just an ex. for brand no:10
First we need to check which cat have brand no 10, in this cat 1,2 have it.
Then for all cutomer in cat 1,2 ; we need count(distinct card_no).

result shoul be like

```
brand_nbr|total_cust
10       | 5
```

I have written the below query to achive this:-

```
select k.brand_nbr,count(distinct l.card_nbr) 
from temp k join temp l on k.cat_nbr=l.cat_nbr
group by 1;
```

It give me proper result but the thing , we have trillion of records in table and when I do run the query it goes on processing like more than 2 hrs.

I need a solution to improve the performance so that it can max in 30 min.
I have checked the amps , there are 16 amps for my database.

Please masters help me out if you have any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only other approach I can think of is using two steps:

```
-- This will remove duplicates
CREATE VOLATILE SET TABLE vt AS
 (
   SELECT k.brand_nbr,l.card_nbr
   FROM temp k JOIN temp l ON k.cat_nbr=l.cat_nbr
  ) 
WITH DATA 
PRIMARY INDEX(brand_nbr)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

-- Now you can simply count without distinct
SELECT brand_nbr, COUNT(*)
FROM vtab
GROUP BY 1;
```

Depending on your data (number of rows per cat_nbr/brand_nbr) this might be faster. Or slower and totally skewed :-)

Btw, I doubt you store 1 trillion rows on a 16 AMP system, this is at least 30TB, maybe 16 **nodes**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create volatile table as a set (as dnoeth suggested), try using an ordered analytical function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
k.brand_Nbr,
COUNT(l.card_nbr) OVER(PARTITION BY k.brand_Nbr) AS cnt
FROM temp k JOIN temp l ON k.cat_nbr=l.cat_nbr
```

Ordered analytical functions don't need `GROUP BY` statement. I am not really sure if it would be actually better than a volatile table regarding performance (since a volatile table mentioned in dnoeth's solution also uses indexing, which theoretically should be better for Teradata), but you can give it a try.